# Specific WFS error - Fiona: fiona.errors.DriverError: '/vsimem/4ec3f86c094340cc8704fe5b9aa0f517

Tags: python, wfs, geopandas, fiona

I am trying to receive some data through several WFS servers. While two work with my code, one gives an error. I don't have enough experience with WFS to see how this one is different from the others.
Perhaps someone can tell me what causes this error. It occurs when running the last line.

My code:

```
from requests import Request
from owslib.wfs import WebFeatureService
import geopandas as gpd
# enable WFS support
import fiona

fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['WFS'] = 'r'

# URL for WFS backend
url = "https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/nwbvaarwegen/wfs?request=GetCapabilities"


# Initialize
wfs = WebFeatureService(url=url)

# Get data from WFS
# -----------------

# Fetch the last available layer
layer = list(wfs.contents)[1]

# Specify the parameters for fetching the data
params = dict(service='WFS', version="1.0.0", request='GetFeature',
      typeName=layer, outputFormat='json')

# Parse the URL with parameters
q = Request('GET', url, params=params).prepare().url

# Read data from URL
data = gpd.read_file(q)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fiona\_shim.pyx", line 83, in fiona._shim.gdal_open_vector
  File "fiona\_err.pyx", line 291, in fiona._err.exc_wrap_pointer
fiona._err.CPLE_OpenFailedError: '/vsimem/0042da5184684564b89dfe3b16a73230' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

Comment: which layer is failing?

Comment: Maybe can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68837404/fiona-not-seeing-shp-file-as-a-recognised-format

Comment: The layer failing is called: nwbvaarwegen:vaarwegvakken. However the other one (nwbvaarwegen:kmmarkeringen) is also failing

Comment: Version 1.0.0 of that service doesn't appear to support json as an output format ~ https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/nwbvaarwegen/wfs?request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS&version=1.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with your Fiona and GeoPandas modules, because the q value is obtained here by the `request` module in JSON format (and not directly by `GeoPandas`). GeoPandas read the resultant JSON file.

```
import geopandas as gpd
print(gpd.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers.keys())
dict_keys(['AeronavFAA', 'ARCGEN', 'BNA', 'DXF', 'CSV', 'OpenFileGDB', 'ESRIJSON', 'ESRI Shapefile', 'GeoJSON', 'GeoJSONSeq', 'GPKG', 'GML', 'GPX', 'GPSTrackMaker', 'Idrisi', 'MapInfo File', 'DGN', 'S57', 'SEGY', 'SUA', 'TopoJSON', 'wml'])
#there is no wfs support here

from requests import Request
from owslib.wfs import WebFeatureService  
wfs_url= "https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/nwbvaarwegen/wfs"
wfs = WebFeatureService(url=wfs_url)
print(wfs.version)
1.0.0
#   supported format for output
print(wfs.getOperationByName('GetFeature').formatOptions)
'{http://www.opengis.net/wfs}KML',
'{http://www.opengis.net/wfs}GML2',
'{http://www.opengis.net/wfs}GML3',
'{http://www.opengis.net/wfs}CSV',
'{http://www.opengis.net/wfs}JSON']
# layers
print(list(wfs.contents))
['nwbvaarwegen:kmmarkeringen', 'nwbvaarwegen:vaarwegvakken']
layer = list(wfs.contents)[1]
# schema of the layer
print(wfs.get_schema(layer))
{'properties': {'vwk_id': 'decimal', 'vwk_begindatum': 'date', 'vwj_id_beg': 'decimal', 'vwj_id_end': 'decimal', 'vaktype': 'string', 'vrt_code': 'string', 'vrt_naam': 'string', 'vwg_nr': 'short', 'vwg_naam': 'string', 'begkm': 'double', 'endkm': 'double'}, 'required': [], 'geometry': 'MultiLineString', 'geometry_column': 'geom'}
# geometry of the layer
print(wfs.get_schema(layer)['geometry'])
MultiLineString
params = dict(service='WFS', version=wfs.version, request='GetFeature',
   typeName=layer, outputFormat='json')
q = Request('GET', wfs_url, params=params).prepare().url
print(q)
https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/nwbvaarwegen/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=nwbvaarwegen%3Avaarwegvakken&outputFormat=json
```

q here is a simple link to a GeoJSON feature collection (https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/nwbvaarwegen/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=nwbvaarwegen%3Avaarwegvakken&outputFormat=json)

Therefore the GeoDataFrame is created from the GeoJSON feature collection.

```
data = gpd.read_file(q)
data.head()
            id  ...                                           geometry
0  vaarwegvakken.1  ...  MULTILINESTRING ((38358.000 394007.000, 38116....
1  vaarwegvakken.2  ...  MULTILINESTRING ((35057.000 398300.000, 34241....
2  vaarwegvakken.3  ...  MULTILINESTRING ((38524.000 387905.000, 38332....
3  vaarwegvakken.4  ...  MULTILINESTRING ((38524.000 387905.000, 38807....
4  vaarwegvakken.5  ...  MULTILINESTRING ((38890.000 388103.000, 39188....
```